# Mapping table with inner join creates duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, entity-framework

I have a program and courses mapping table. One program can have multiple courses. I created a mapping table for program to course table(oneToMany). But when I do inner join I am getting duplicates which is not expected for me. I need to filter based on course like find program with a course name so need to join two table. I have two doubts here

1. I avoid duplicate with distinct keyboard. I need join for filtering with courses, will it be possible to avoid duplicate with out distinct keyword as distinct may hurt my query performance
2. Will be it possible to select all courses as semi column separated in one query incase that is causing duplicate.

I am using Java entity(Hibernate) for so oneToMany relationship is building this query out of the box.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT SeqNo, pgm_id, start_date, end_date, pgm_description, location, timings
From 
PGM_DETAILS T1
INNER JOIN COURSE_DETAILS T2
ON T1.pgm_id=T2.pgm_id
WHERE T1.pgm_id=110 and T2.course_name in('C bascis','Java Basics');
```

**Desired Result**

```
 SeqNo|pgm_id  |start_date|end_date |pgm_description|location|timings
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    |   110  | 12-Sep-22|20-Sep-22|My test PGM    | NY     |3-5 PM |C basics;Java Basics;
```

**pgm_details**

```
SeqNo|pgm_id  |start_date|end_date |pgm_description|location|timings
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |   110  | 12-Sep-22|20-Sep-22|My test PGM    | NY     |3-5 PM  
2    |   101  | 14-Oct-22|21-Oct-22|My Second      | NJ     |8-9 AM  
3    |   102  | 21-Aug-22|30-Sep-22|My JPGM        | NK     |3-5 PM  
4    |   103  | 08-Dec-22|29-Dec-22|Summer Pj      | CA     |7-8 AM
5    |   104  | 12-Sep-22|20-Sep-22|My Ny PGM      | FE     |3-5 PM  
6    |   105  | 12-Sep-22|20-Sep-22|My FE PGM      | CE     |1-5 PM  
7    |   106  | 12-Sep-22|20-Sep-22|My IN PGM      | NJ     |4-7 PM
```

**course_details**

```
mapping_id | pgm_id  | course_name
-------------------------------------------
  1        | 110     | C basics
  2        | 110     | Java basics
  3        | 110     | python basics
  4        | 110     | Angular basics
  5        | 101     | PERL basics
  6        | 101     | Linux basics
  7        | 101     | Spring basics
  8        | 101     | React basics
  9        | 101     | Javascript basics
  10       | 102     | Windows basics
  11       | 102     | Linux basics
  12       | 103     | Spring basics
  13       | 104     | React basics
  14       | 105     | Javascript basics
```

Comment: Please show your desired results

Comment: @DaleK done. I need to get with out duplicates and without using distinct keyword

Comment: The duplicates are because of your table course_details. You are filtering on 'C basics' and 'Java basics', both have the same pgm_id. Select just once course_details.mapping_id and you will see the values 1 and 2 in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SeqNo, pgm_id, start_date, end_date, pgm_description, location, timings,
(  
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mapping_id) 
   FROM COURSE_DETAILS T2
   WHERE T1.pgm_id=T2.pgm_id

) AS MappingIds
From PGM_DETAILS T1
```

Comment: For this I will not be able to filter based on courses right?